# AWS Amplify GraphQL - One to Many connections return empty list when queried

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, connection, aws-amplify

I've been following the AWS GraphQL CLI guide for setting up an API for my app, but am having trouble with connections.

The following is my current Graphql schema, with some attributes removed

```
type Employee @model {
  id: ID!
  employment: [Employment!] @connection(name: "byEmployeeIDByCompanyID", fields: ["id"])
}

type Company @model {
  id: ID!
  employees: [Employment!] @connection(name: "byCompanyIDByDateHired", fields: ["id"])
}

type Employment @model
  @key(name: "byEmployeeIDByCompanyID", fields: ["employeeID", "companyID"], queryField: "employmentByEmployeeIDByCompanyID") {
  id: ID!
  companyID: ID!
  employeeID: ID!
  company: Company! @connection(fields: ["companyID"])
  employee: Employee! @connection(fields: ["employeeID"])
}
```

When I query Employees or Companys, [Employment] always returns an empty array. Do I need to edit the resolvers for these fields? They should work out of the box, no?

From my understanding, using @key with 'name' and multiple 'fields' creates a secondary index on the table, and specifying that key with @connection tells the connection to use that key instead of the tables primary index. In the "byEmployeeIDByCompanyID" key, for example, employeeID is the partition key, and companyID is the sort key. A query on the "employmentByEmployeeIDByCompanyID" queryField with an employeeID but no companyID returns all the employments for a given employee, which is what I want, so why isn't the connection working?

Comment: If I edit the resolver for Employee.employment or Company.employees, I can have it perform a simple query on the Employee table, using a hard-coded employeeID/companyID. I'm trying to access employeeID/companyID inside the query with $ctx, but I haven't been able to yet.

Answer (score 0):

I found success in editing the resolvers, so I'm going to go with this for now. For Employee.employment, I added:

```
"index": "byEmployeeIDByCompanyID",
```

to the request mapping template, and changed the query from:

```
{
  "expression": "#partitionKey = :partitionKey",
  "expressionNames": {
      "#partitionKey": "id"
  },
  "expressionValues": {
      ":partitionKey": {
          "S": "$context.source.id"
    }
  }
}
```

to

```
{
  "expression": "#partitionKey = :partitionKey",
  "expressionNames": {
      "#partitionKey": "employeeID"
  },
  "expressionValues": {
      ":partitionKey": {
          "S": "$context.source.id"
    }
  }
}
```